# Effect of group by if partition by used or not used

Tags: group-by, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm working on data from google analytics in Bigquery.
I wrote the query to fetch the previous pagepath by lag(pagepath) over (Partition by pagepath order by hitnumber).
`Select  lag(pagepath) over (Partition by pagepath order by hitnumber) as previous page,pagepath,hitnumber,clientid from table`
I wanted to know if I'm grouping the column with pagepath in my query and I don't use partition by , just order by in over() function, why result is different?

`Select  lag(pagepath) over (order by hitnumber) as previous page,pagepath,hitnumber,clientid from table group by pagepath`

Comment: "why result is different?" - can you show us some sample data and how the results look different?

Comment: Please, post the results you get in both queries and the desired result